# copying a LinkedList with a double pointer

Tags: c

Inspired from this [article](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/), I've attempted to copy a LinkedList with double pointers (pointer to pointer).

definition

```
typedef struct MyNode MyNode;

struct MyNode {
    int value;
    MyNode *next;
}
```

implementation

```
MyNode *CreateNode(int value) {
    MyNode *node = malloc(sizeof(MyNode));
    node->value = value;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}


int main() {
    MyNode *an_existing_list = CreateNode(1); // edit, source list
    an_existing_list->next = CreateNode(2);
    an_existing_list->next->next = CreateNode(3);


    MyNode *cursor = an_existing_list; // an existing list as a source


    MyNode **previous = NULL; // double pointer reference

    while (cursor) { // iterate the exisitng list

        MyNode *temp = CreateNode(cursor->value); // create a new node  

        if (previous) { // if a node was created in the previous iteration
            (*previous)->next = temp; // access the actual node and set previous' next to this new node
        }

        previous = &temp; // for the next iteration

        cursor = cursor->next; // next node
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem**: I'm running into some of endless copy of the same node into next->next->next

Comment: `temp` is on the stack.  Saving a pointer to it in `previous` will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: I see, I tried with declaration of `My *temp` outside the while loop as well

Comment: cursor is pointing to the source linked list to be copied.

Comment: Yes, please post an [mcve].

Comment: edited with an existing list, is there something else I can add? I think code is complete now.

Comment: I think the issue is that `previous` is holding and sticking on the `temp` pointer and temp keeps on changing, so perhaps this implementation is wrong, there has to be another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenters habe already pointed out your mistake: You try to save the address of a local variable in the list links. That local variable goes out of scope after the while loop body ends, that is imemdiately. That means your program invokes undefined behaviour, in your case an endless loop.

But you are also missing the point of the article: You use a pointer to node pointer in order not to have to treat the case where your head pointer is null as special. In other words, you don't need `previous`. The pointer to pointer `p` already deals with the question where the link to the new node is stored, namely at `*p`, which holds

- the address of your list head at the beginning (a) and
- the address of the `next` field of the preceding node after that (b).

Your duplicate function should look like this:

```
MyNode *duplicate(const MyNode *cursor)
{
    MyNode *dup = NULL;
    MyNode **p = &dup;                  // (a)

    while (cursor) {
        *p = create(cursor->value);

        p = &(*p)->next;                // (b)
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return dup;
}
```

See it [in action on ideone](https://ideone.com/QejYFY).

Comment: Here: `previous = &temp;`

Comment: superb. @MOehm.

Comment: your version of LinkedList is even shorter than the article. you work with double pointer alone in most of the functions.

Comment: @AppDeveloper: Yes. It's a useful technique. It makes for concise code and it works with other linked structures such as trees, too.